# Passing custom parameters to ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I built a custom ValidationAttribute so I can validate unique email addresses in my system. However, I'd like to pass in a custom parameter somehow to add more logic to my validation.

```
public class UniqueEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        //I need the original value here so I won't validate if it hasn't changed.
        return value != null && Validation.IsEmailUnique(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Like this?

```
public class StringLengthValidatorNullable : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinStringLength { get; set; }
    public int MaxStringLength { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var length = value.ToString().Length;

        if (length < MinStringLength || length >= MaxStringLength)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
[StringLengthValidatorNullable(MinStringLength = 1, MaxStringLength = 16)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Comment: Kind of, but I can only pass constants that way, correct? I want to pass in the original value to compare to the value that is being validated.

Comment: Yes, only constants. I am not sure if I get your question. The validator can just validate the current value of a poperty, it does not know about any past values of a property.

Comment: That's specifically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So you just can do a database call in your validator to compare the current value to the original value. You can also add a extra "orginal value" property to your model and compare to this value. You should be able do access other properties of the object via the ValidationContext.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check out the ValidationContext. I think that's what I need.

Comment: The ValidationContext pointed me to the correct place. This link contains the method I used: http://anthonyvscode.com/2011/07/14/mvc-3-requiredif-validator-for-multiple-values/

Comment: This could also have been done by a RegularExpression attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You could also pass parameters that are other properties in the same model.

Create a custom validation attribute:

```
public class SomeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    //A property to hold the name of the one you're going to use.
    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Get the value of the property using reflection.
        var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
        var otherPropertyValue = (bool)otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (value != null && otherPropertyValue)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Invalid property message.");
    }
}
```

Then pass the name of the property you're going to use.

```
    public class RequestModel 
    {
        public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }

        [SomeValidation(OtherProperty = "SomeProperty")]
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it did not pass anything like I thought it would.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar requirement where I had to pass along a value to a custom attribute.

The issue here is that Attribute decorations don't allow **variables**. 
You get compile time error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

Here is how I was able to do it:

**In Controller**

```
[FineGrainAuthorization]
public class SomeABCController : Controller
{
    public int SomeId { get { return 1; } }
}
```

**In Attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FineGrainAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        ControllerBase callingController = filterContext.Controller;
        var someIdProperty = callingController.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name.Equals("SomeId")).First();
        int someId = (int) someIdProperty.GetValue(callingController, null);
    }
}
```

Remember that the string inside `.Name.Equals("SomeId")` must case match the declaration `public int SomeId`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like @Oliver's answer (that's what I'd do, anyway), but then I noticed that you do not want to pass constants.

What about something like this, then?

```
public static class MyConfig
{
    public static int MinStringLength { get; set; }
    public static int MaxStringLength { get; set; }
    public static SomeObject otherConfigObject { get; set; }
}
```

And then access `MyConfig.MinStringLength` from validation? 
I'll agree that it isn't too pretty, though.