# How to pass a field or dynamically changing value to a custom validator in C#?

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have a class

```
public class File {
    [Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "The Header should contain at least one element")]    
    public List<string> Header { get; set; }
    [ColumnLenghts]
    public List<int> ColumnLenghts { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
```

and in my custom validator I want to check

```
public class ColumnLenghtsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<int> columnLengths = (List<int>) value;
        // other checks
        if(columnLengths.Count != Header.Count) {
            return new ValidationResult(" number of column length does not match to headers");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
I could not find a way to pass `Header` field to the custom validator.

I have tried

```
public class File {
    [Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "The Header should contain at least one element")]    
    public List<string> Header { get; set; }
    [ColumnLenghts (headerCount = Header.Count)]
    public List<int> ColumnLenghts { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
```

```
public class ColumnLenghtsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int headerCount {get; set;}

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<int> columnLengths = (List<int>) value;
        // other checks
        if(columnLengths.Count != headerCount) {
            return new ValidationResult(" number of column length does not match to headers");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and I am getting the error: `an object reference is required for the non-static field`

**Question**: Is it possible to pass a field or maybe dynamically changing value to a custom validator?

Comment: Method: ValidationAttribute.IsValid :Parameter value - Type:Object  comment:The value of the object to validate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.isvalid?view=net-6.0

Comment: You should be able to access the value via reflection through the validation context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280462/619252

Comment: @GabrielNegut can you please change your comment to the answer. So I could accept it as solution.